# What about sodium triphosphate in drinking water?

Tags: water-treatment

Recently, at my place, a sort of filter for hard water was installed. They told me that it contains sodium triphosphate which is dissolved into all the water that enter home, i.e. both cold and hot water to prevent calcium carbonate to accumulate into the plumbing system, dishwasher, etc.... From what I can understand, there is no way this device is considering the flow rate in order to decide how much sodium goes into the water. It just happens.

According to what I googled, [sodium triphosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_triphosphate) is used as an additive in many foods and, even though is not considered harmful, high levels may lead to health risks. Also, I have found some links (not in english) stating that such devices should be installed in the hot water plumbings since sodium triphosphate and calcium carbonate interact only at certain temperatures. According to these sources, drinking cold water is not harmful since no chemical reaction took place (but still sodium is present in the water, I believe) and, also, once I use the same cold water for cooking it gets hot and a reaction may take place.

I am quite puzzled and I don't know what to do with this filter. I can move it to hot water only, or I can keep it where it is (both cold and hot) if it's not harmful but I couldn't find any clear information. Is there something that may help?

EDIT 1:
[this](https://www.pineco.com/eng/products/dosing/dosing-products/salifos) is the exact product I am using.

EDIT 2:
its chemical formula is Na5 P3 O10

EDIT 3:
[this](https://www.pineco.com/eng/products/dosing/polyphosphate-dosers/kit-pineco-facile-pg-fos-3-4-and-1) seems to be the device that was installed and [this](https://www.pineco.com/eng/products/dosing/polyphosphate-dosers/pinedos-maxi) is one of the components that is taking care of the dosing (that is equal to 4-5ppm of sodium triphosphate, apparently)

Comment: How is this filter installed ? Is it on a bypass of the main pipe ? How is the flow controlled ? Trisodium phosphate is a bit soluble in water. So, without control, it should be quickly dissolved and eliminated.

Comment: it is installed at the very entrance of the water inside the house and, as far as I know, the flow is not controlled in any way. 
Also, If it is quickly dissolved...what is the purpose of having it in the first place?

Comment: If the sodium triphosphate is in big chunks, it will not be quickly dissolved. But I am afraid it is not sodium triphosphate. By reading your reference, it is sodium polyphosphate. There are several sodium polyphosphates. For example, the sodium tripolyphosphate is poorly soluble and is known to be useful for removing calcium ions from tap water. It is not a dangerous substance. You can maintain it in your filter. It will make a complex ion with calcium, so there will not be any calcareous deposits in your tubing and other equipment. It seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @Maurice I added the exact chemical formula!

Comment: It may not have immediate negative effects, but it is even more aggressive to enviroment by the phosphate load of waste water than the washing formulas for washing machines. As the latter treat just water used for machine washing. The former treat all the water.

Comment: @Maurice Sodium triphosphate:  *Sodium triphosphate (STP), also sodium tripolyphosphate (STPP), or tripolyphosphate (TPP) .....  Not to be confused with Trisodium phosphate Na3PO4.* Note that sodium diphosphate is not Na2HPO4 either, but Na4P2O7.

Comment: @Poutnik the fact that it does not have _immediate_ negative effects is not reassuring. Also, the fact that it is harmful for the environment and is worse than a washing machine soap...well that is even more not reassuring.

Comment: @Poutnik, yes that is what I found by googling it. It looks like it should be applied to hot water only, to avoid exposure with drinking water (assuming one only uses cold water for drinking and cooking). Doing so still harms the environment, though.

Comment: yeah well, a washing machine is replaceable while health is not. I have zero doubt about my priorities, in this case. Lets see if I can find something else or someone has something to add.

Comment: I use TSP as garden fertilizer, plants do well  ,so no problem in limited amounts. I have acidic soil so I want alkaline fertilizer.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Trisodium phosphate (TSP) is different than sodium triphosphate. TSP is a great fertilizer, which is why its use as an ingredient in detergents has been regulated in the USA due to the fact that it causes algae blooms in lakes and ponds downstream from where waste treatment effluent is released.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be safe, provided that you are putting it into one of the delivery systems that it’s made for which I found through the link you provided.

Here is one of the delivery systems:

https://www.pineco.com/eng/products/dosing/polyphosphate-dosers/spillo-polyphosphates-doser-dm

Per the specs, it delivers 3ppm, which means that you’re only introducing 1ml per 333L of water, which is approximately what the average person uses per day.

Contributing to phosphate load shouldn’t be a concern as someone (with “normal” diet &renal function) has a concentration of 10-300ppm of phosphorus in their urine!

This company also sells water filters for regionally specific water issues like high arsenic, and water softeners with different ion exchange resins based on the ions present in the water. They appear to have a solid understanding of drinking water chemistry, but it’s your domestic water, not mine, so *caveat emptor*

Comment: Hm, but 3 ppm can hardly make any difference for hard water. E.g. if we have a hard water 25 dGH ( old unit, old school ), it means 250 mg of CaO equivalent. 
And as 1 CaO is equivalent to 1 Na5P3O10, forming complex, it is approx 250*(5*23+3*31+10*16)/(40+16)=1640 mg of Na5P3O10, so 1640 ppm. It would be less, as there is no need to cover all calcium.

Comment: ok! so yes, I checked which device is the one I have installed and edited the question accordingly. I haven't thought about checking on it.

Comment: also, I wanted to add that you considered 333l of water per day but we only use roughly 7/8l for actual drinking and cooking hence the amount of phosphorus should be even lower, right?

Comment: @Poutnik yes, agreed this won’t do much as a primary water softener. The website mentions that it can be installed after the water softener to reduce scaling in pipes as water softeners aren’t 100% effective.

Comment: @gabt that 333L is average household use for ALL water, including washing & showering to understand how much phosphate was being introduced to the waste water as far as environmental impact is concerned. You’re only consuming a trace amount from the water you drink added by the system as I imagine most of it is reacting with the water before it leaves the tap.

Comment: @JackSpencer ok, so...if it already reacted, then what? I guess I am still drinking some residues that are as not-healthy as the original compound.